# Error file system check

Tags: filesystems, systemd, fsck

I enabled the package e2fsprogs and always when the system starts it return the following error (when partition mounting):

```
Jan 01 00:00:03 xxxx systemd[1]: Found device /dev/mmcblk0p3.
Jan 01 00:00:03 xxxx systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on /dev/mmcblk0p3...
Jan 01 00:00:04 xxxx systemd-fsck[86]: read_bad_blocks_file: No such file or directory while trying to open -M
Jan 01 00:00:04 xxxx systemd-fsck[86]: fsck failed with error code 8.
Jan 01 00:00:04 xxxx systemd-fsck[86]: Ignoring error.
```

Apparently any problem occurs with the partition but i would like to know how to fix it and if this problem can cause some problem on the future.

> /dev/mmcblk0p3 on /var type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

Comment: What device is this? `/dev/mmcblk0p3` is usually some form of flash storage. What filesystem is actually in use on it? Do `mount` and add the output to your question.

Comment: /dev/mmcblk0p3 on /var type ext4 (rw,relatime,data=ordered)

Comment: It looks like systemd is invoking fsck with the wrong options. It's probably doing something like `fsck -L -M ...` where `-L` is interpreted as "the following argument is the file containing the list of bad blocks" and then `-M` is encountered. As `-M` is not a valid option for e2fsck the problem is in the way e2fsck is being called. Check the systemd config for fsck.

Comment: [Unit]  
Description=File System Check on %f  
Documentation=man:systemd-fsck@.service(8)  
DefaultDependencies=no
BindsTo=%i.device
After=systemd-readahead-collect.service systemd-readahead-replay.service %i.device
Before=shutdown.target

Comment: How can i change it (-M)?

Comment: Sorry, can't help; I'm staying away from systemd as long as I can.

Comment: why? kkkkkkkkkk

Comment: becuase I'm one of those grey-bearded Unix types that resists change :-) Seriously though, I still have doubts about systemd's maturity. I won't get into any further discussions, there's been enough said on the subject already.

Comment: I understand... anyway tks for your help...